# Thunderbird Add-Ons Development in 2016? XUL recommended?

Tags: thunderbird-addon

I am trying to get into Thunderbird extension development and do not find much or only a lot legacy information on that.

I find a lot of information that extensions in Firefox and Thunderbird work the same, but:

XPCOM/XUL based extension are not recommended anymore?
WebExtension are used in FF but in TB?
Can I still use XPCOM/XUL based extensions in Thunderbid and does it makes sense?

Answer (score 4):

XUL based extensions (either as [Overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions) or [Bootstrapped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_Extensions)) are currently the only ones supported for Thunderbird.

The newer WebExtensions or the Add-on SDK only work in Firefox. As far as I know, there are currently no plans to add support for them in Thunderbird. Instead, Thunderbird tries to delay the deprecation of XUL as long as possible (https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/webextensions-api-and-deprecation-of-xul-xpcom-and-xbl/3459/4, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tb-planning/UIVHTbhjrU8).

Comment: Thankl you very much! Can you maybe provide a link to useful source where Mozilla explains this situation/this plans not including them in TB?

Comment: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/08/21/the-future-of-developing-firefox-add-ons/

Comment: found that but maybe there is more ;-)

Comment: added 2 links in the answer.